# Limit divergence under squaring

Tags: limits

This may be a very simple question, but I'm stumped.

Suppose two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are positive and increasing.  Also suppose that the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)-g(n)$ diverges to $+\infty$.  Does that imply that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^2(n)-g^2(n)$ also diverges to $+\infty$?

This seems to be one of those problems where the intuition suggests that it's true, but in fact there is a counterexample... My usual tools of attacking limits (the limit chain rule, L'Hopital's) don't seem to apply here.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

By these inequalities
$$f(n)+g(n)\ge f(n)-g(n)\ge1\;\forall n\ge n_0$$
$$f^2(n)-g^2(n)=(f(n)-g(n))(f(n)+g(n))\ge f(n)-g(n)\;\forall n\ge n_0$$
we deduce the desired result.

Comment: Very clever answer, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just realized the functions are positive and increasing, I apologize!

Comment: @DanZimm The hypothesis is that $f$ and $g$ are positive increasing functions.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane yes I'm sorry - I've had a similar question but without that hypothesis ;P

Comment: @DanZimm Never mind:-)